# use of preposition: regarding

Tags: prepositions

which one is correct? Or neither?

(1) Will everyone be notified regarding the number of prizes they would receive?

or

(2) Will everyone be notified the number of prizes they would receive?

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion:

> Will everyone be notified regarding the number of prizes they would receive?

is perfectly fine, although it could be recast as:

> - Will everyone be notified of the number of prizes they would receive?
> - Will everyone be notified about their prize count?

However, the second sentence suggested in the question:

> Will everyone be notified the number of prizes they would receive?

in my view does not work -- indeed i would call it wrong. Some verbs, such as "tell" or "show", can be used in that way, but "notify" cannot. You can be "shown something" but you cannot be "notified something" only "notified of something" or "notified about something" -- the preposition is required.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 would be better; however try rewording as follows: Regarding the number of prizes everyone is to receive, will there be notification?

Comment: that is grammatical but in my view awkward and not natural.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is fine. The other way of saying that would be **with regard to**, **pertaining to** and **..related to**.